# if there a better way to write this if statment in java

Tags: java, if-statement, simplify

So is there a way to simplify this to make is smaller in anyway?

```
else if(selectedCards.size() == 3
            && cardAt(selectedCards.get(0)).pointValue() + cardAt(selectedCards.get(1)).pointValue() + cardAt(selectedCards.get(2)).pointValue() == 0 
            && !cardAt(selectedCards.get(0)).rank().equals(cardAt(selectedCards.get(1)).rank()) 
            && !cardAt(selectedCards.get(0)).rank().equals(cardAt(selectedCards.get(2)).rank())
            && !cardAt(selectedCards.get(1)).rank().equals(cardAt(selectedCards.get(2)).rank()))
```

Comment: you can make a method[return boolean] to reduce codes `cardAt(selectedCards.get(0)).rank().equals(cardAt(selectedCards.get(1)).rank()) `

Comment: Maybe create a function which performs those validations, name it appropriately and call it in the if

Comment: Do any of the answers below solve your problem? Do you need any more information? Please consider accepting an answer, http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can see you're trying to test if the 3 cards have different ranks. An easier way to test this is to put them into a Set and see if the set size is same as selected set. This scales to any number of selected cards...

```
public boolean differentRanks(List<Integer> selectedCards) {
    Set<Integer> ranks = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for (int card : selectedCards) {
        ranks.add(cardAt(card).rank());
    }
    return ranks.size() == selectedCards.size();
}
```

I'd also create a method to total the points for the selected cards...

```
public int sum(List<Integer> selectedCards) {
    int total;
    for (int card : selectedCards) {
        total += cardAt(card).pointValue();
    }
    return total;
}
```

So the condition would end up

```
} else if (selectedCards.size() == 3 && sum(selectedCards) == 0 && 
           differentRanks(selectedCards) {
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be one option:

```
else if(selectedCards.size() == 3
        && cardAt(selectedCards.get(0)).pointValue() +        cardAt(selectedCards.get(1)).pointValue() + cardAt(selectedCards.get(2)).pointValue() == 0 
        && !(cardAt(selectedCards.get(0)).rank().equals(cardAt(selectedCards.get(1)).rank())).equals(cardAt(selectedCards.get(2)).rank()) )
```

To make more readable this condition you could do something like this:

```
//here you extract the values you need only once and use them in your condition block below
        int cardsSize = selectedCards.size();
        int pointValue0 = cardsSize == 3 ? cardAt(selectedCards.get(0)).pointValue() : 0;
        int pointValue1 = cardsSize == 3 ? cardAt(selectedCards.get(1)).pointValue() : 0;
        int pointValue2 = cardsSize == 3 ? cardAt(selectedCards.get(2)).pointValue() : 0;           
        bool rankEquals = CompareRanks(cardAt(selectedCards.get(0)),cardAt(selectedCards.get(1)),cardAt(selectedCards.get(2));

        if (<condition>) {
            //block of sentences
        } else if (cardsSize == 3 && (pointValue0 + pointValue1 + pointValue2) == 0 && !rankEquals )
```

I'm suggesting the creation of a function called "CompareRanks" where you receive 3 different objects (result of "cardAt") and you get the rank in there and compare if the values are the same or not.

This option leads you to more lines of code but is cleaner and more readable for any person besides you.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion most readable:

```
else if(selectedCards.size() == 3 && checkRanks(selectedCards))
{
    //...
}

//...

private boolean checkRanks(List<Card> cards)
{
    Card zeroCard = cardAt(selectedCards.get(0));
    Card firstCard = cardAt(selectedCards.get(1));
    Card secondCard = cardAt(selectedCards.get(2));

    boolean isZero = zeroCard.pointValue() + firstCard.pointValue() +      secondCard.pointValue() == 0;

    boolean zeroCardRankNotEqualFirst = !zeroCard.rank().equals(firstCard.rank())
    boolean zeroCardRankNotEqualSecond = !zeroCard.rank().equals(secondCard.rank())
    boolean firstCardRankNotEqualsSecond = !firstCard.rank().equals(secondCard.rank()); 

    return isZero && zeroCardRankNotEqualFirst && zeroCardRankNotEqualSecond && firstCardRankNotEqualsSecond;
}
```

Comment: I'd just like to add that readability is what you should be concerned with the most. The JVM will compile and optimize readable code into the same set of instructions as other implementations that may seem more efficient. This in mind, I think this solution is very good.